# Calling Parent class method, from an object pointer?

Tags: c++

Assuming I have a class B derived from A

A defined foo() and also, B defines foo()

I have a method in another class that receives a B* (pointer to B). In that function, can I call the A::foo(), just by using the pointer to B the function received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following would do what you want:

```
void fun(B* b){
    b->A::foo();
}
```

Comment: As long as `A::foo` is visible to `void fun(B*)`. and `B` derives publicly from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Or, of course, you can do it with type casting:

```
((A*)b)->foo();
```

or in c++ style with safety check:

```
dynamic_cast<A*>(b)->foo();
```